# How to mount from command line like the Nautilus does?

Tags: linux, gnome, mount

On my Ubuntu linux box I can easily mount USB connected drives or CDROM clicking on devices icons that I can found on the Desktop.

For example if I click on a USB connected drive icon the following things happen:

- a /media/LABEL directory is automatically created (where LABEL is the label of the disk and may vary from disk to disk)
- the filesystem on the device is mounted on /media/LABEL

This process is significantly different from mounting using the `mount` command. In particular:

- you don't need to be root (or you don't need to modify /etc/fstab to allow ordinary user to mount the device)
- the /media/LABEL directory is automatically created
- the name of the directory changes according the volume label.

There is a command line command that behaves like the Gnome GUI mounting facilities does?

Comment: I decided to use `/etc/fstab` to mount my disk at boot, probably not what you want, but it works reliably when the SO thread is locked and none of the options seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [`pmount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/pmount.1.html) command for usage information

Comment: pmount doesn't have few features of nautilus. 1) nautilus lists available drives. when i press tab pmount doesn't list my windows partition. and if it would, i doubt it would list it as "Windows7_OS", but this is not that important. 2) when i pmount something, i have to create a directory for the mounting point. nautilus does it automatically. it seems that nautilus has its own database for mounting, is there a way to access it?

Comment: pmount uses HAL, which is being depreciated, so I would recommend looking at the post by @mwx below

Comment: @kirill_igum *"when i press tab pmount doesn't list my windows partition"* *smile* you are a funny one. Yes, I guess you could do that by writing you own *bash-expand rule function*. I guess what you want is `udisks`, see another answer below.

Comment: pmount doesnt work for non removable devices :(

Answer (score 46):

What you are looking for is `gio mount` (it recently replaced `gvfs-mount`, which replaced `gnome-mount`).

There is a [man page here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/gio.1.html) or you can just type `gio help mount` for the details

The basic usage is:

`gio mount --list --detail` to get a list of mounted and mountable volumes

`gio mount [-u] <volume>` to [un]mount it, e.g. `gio mount smb://server/share` or `gio mount WINDOWS`.

Sadly, there seems to be a bug that results in a "Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount" message trying to mount by volume name, but `gvfs-mount -d /dev/<devicename>` might work.

Comment: On Oneiric and Natty gvfs-mount smb://server/share seems to work out of the box.  You might want to ensure you have gvfs-fuse installed.

Comment: [`gvfs-mount` also requires DBus](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44318/13308).

Comment: How I mounted my camera: `gio mount --list --detail` there was a line like `activation_root=gphoto2://Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers` then I did `gio mount gphoto2://Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers`. Now I can see my camera's files in `"/run/home/$UID/gvfs/gphoto2:host=Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers/DCIM"` (need quotes because of the `ghoto2:host=`), where [$UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) is probably `1000`.

Comment: 2023: `udisksctl` is capable of passing options like `ro`, `rw`, `umask` and etc. directly to `mount`, I don't think `gio` can do that. But one thing I like about `gio` is `gio mount -li`, the handy list of *mountable* devices.

Answer (score 27):

In modern distributions, HAL is no longer used. The `pmount` still exists, but it is deprecated. Use:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdXN
```

### Answer Update:

The `udisksctl` command is being used as an alternative to the `udisks` command. This can be used the same way, `-b` is just to be appended to define the block device.

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXN
```

Comment: I also found udisksctl (part of the same system) to be quick and effective. 
ie: 
     udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb

Comment: p.s. I made a python script that does it with udisks here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22454071/493272

Comment: You're the man now, dog!

Comment: I cant even remember how long I am looking for this... thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It's called [ivman](http://ivman.sourceforge.net/) and handles all HAL events. I start it when running [ion3](http://www.modeemi.fi/~tuomov/ion/). I simply start `ivman` as a daemon process, but has added the program to my sudoers file:

```
cat /etc/sudoers
[...]
ivman {hostname}=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/init, /usr/sbin/hibernate
[...]
```

so that it can manage power settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Gnome itself handles the mounting—it's HAL. So if HAL is running, you should be able to automount. I assume that `pmount` talks to HAL somehow, and that would be the way to handle unmounting. I hope this gets you started, at least.

Comment: The gnome nautilus mounts are found here 

`/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share/path-to-mount/`

Comment: and for existing mounts it would be as follows

`run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.1.100,share=share-name/path-to-folder/`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gnome-mount for mounting / unmounting from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I plug in my USB device, type "gnome-volume-manager" and this seems to do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

That would be "`devkit-disks --mount /dev/sdxx`" where `xx` is the letter and number of the partition to mount...

Answer (score 0):

I have a script to do what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
#====================================================================
# udmount.sh - mounts partitons by volume label.
#  usage: udmount.sh <label> [rw|ro|u]
#   rw - mount read-only (default) 
#   rw - mount read-write 
#   u  - unmount
# 
# Mounts on /media/<label>. Tested on Mint 13 and Fedora 19.
# Use and/or modify at your own risk. Your mileage may vary.
# Caveats:
#   * No spaces in volume label. Won't work.
#   * If the mount point (/media/<label>) already exists,
#     (usually from an unclean shutdown), udmount will mount
#     the volume on /media/<label>_  
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You can view the GNU General Public License for this program at
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
# Copyright 2013 maxdev137@sbcglobal.net
#====================================================================

BEEP=$'\a'
VLABEL="$1"     # volume label
MPOINT="/media" # default mount point for gnome-mount/udisks
YN=""           # yes/no string

c_red() { echo -n $(tput setaf 1)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }
c_grn() { echo -n $(tput setaf 2)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }
c_yel() { echo -n $(tput setaf 3)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }
c_blu() { echo -n $(tput setaf 4)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }
c_pur() { echo -n $(tput setaf 5)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }
c_aqu() { echo -n $(tput setaf 6)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }
c_wht() { echo -n $(tput setaf 7)$1$(tput sgr0) ; }

Y="YEP " ; Y_c=$(c_grn "$Y")
N="NOPE" ; N_c=$(c_red "$N")
SNAME=`echo "$0" | sed -e 's|.*/\(.*\)$|\1|'`

#--------------------------------------------------
AMV_LABEL=""    # already mounted volume label
MMSG=""         # "is mounted on" msg
AMF=0           # already mounted flag
AMV=""          # already mounted volume (from "mount -l")
AMV_DETAILS=""  # already mounted volume details
AMV_HELPER=""   # "uhelper" subsystem for mount/unmount ("hal" or "udisks")
COPT="$2"       # command line option
MOPT="ro"       # user input for mount option
UOPT="ro"       # udisk mount options

#--------------------------------------------------
_usage ()      { echo "usage: $SNAME LABEL [rw|ro|u]" ; }
_error()       { echo "!!! Error: $1. !!!" >&2 ; echo -n "$BEEP"; _usage ; exit 1 ; }
_error_parm()  { _error "$2 Parameter Missing [$1]" ; }
_error_parm2() { _error "Command is wrong (only \"rw, ro, or u\") is alowed, not \"$1\"" ; }

_unmount () {
  ### unmount ###
  if [ "$COPT" = "u" ] ; then
    MPOINT=`echo "$AMV" | grep "\[$VLABEL\]" |sed -e 's|^.* \(/.*\) type.*$|\1|'`
    #echo "unmount MPOINT = [$MPOINT]"
    if [ -z "$MPOINT" ] ; then
      echo "$N_c - $VLABEL not mounted."
    else
      _MSG=`umount "$MPOINT" 2>&1`
      _STATUS=$?
      if [ "$_STATUS" -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "$Y_c - \"$MPOINT\" is now unmounted"
      else echo "$N_c - unmount \"$MPOINT\" failed ($_MSG)"
      fi
    fi
  fi
}

#--------------------------------------------------
[ -n "$VLABEL" ]  || _error_parm "$VLABEL" "Volume Label"

### command line option checck
case "$COPT" in
  "ro" ) ;;
  "rw" ) ;;
  "u"  ) ;;
     * ) _error_parm2 "$COPT" ;;
esac

### is VLABEL already mounted?
AMV=$(mount -l | grep "\[$VLABEL\]")
AMF=$?

### VLABEL is mounted somewhere
if  [ $AMF -eq 0 ] ; then
  AMV_LABEL=$(echo "$AMV" | sed 's/^.* \[\(.*\)\]$/\1/')
  AMV_DETAILS=$(echo $AMV | sed 's|^.*on \(.*\) \[.*$|on \"\1\"|')
  AMV_UHELPER=$(echo $AMV | grep uhelper | sed 's/^.*uhelper=\(.*\)).*$/\1/')
  #echo "AMV = [$AMV]"
  #echo "AMV_LABEL = [$AMV_LABEL]"
  #echo "AMV_DETAILS = [$AMV_DETAILS]"
  #echo "AMV_UHELPER = [$AMV_UHELPER]"

  ### unmount ###
  [ "$COPT" = "u" ] && _unmount && exit $?

  ### mounted on MPOINT (usually /media)
  if [ -d "$MPOINT/$VLABEL" ] ; then
    MOPT="ro" ; YN="$N_c"
    [ -w "$MPOINT/$VLABEL" ] && MOPT="rw"
    [ "$MOPT" = "$COPT" ]     && YN="$Y_c"
  ### mounted somewhere else
  else
    MOPT=$(echo "$AMV_DETAILS" | sed 's/^.*(\(.*\)).*$/\1/')
  fi
  echo "$N_c - $VLABEL is already mounted \"$MOPT\" $AMV_DETAILS"

### $VLABEL is not mounted anywhere, decide on "rw" or "ro"
else
  if [ "$COPT" = "u" ] ; then
    echo "$N_c - \"$VLABEL\" is not mounted"
  else
    MOPT="ro"
    [ "$COPT" = "rw" ] && MOPT="rw"
    echo "udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/$VLABEL $UOPT"
    udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-label/"$VLABEL" --mount-options "$MOPT"
    _STATUS=$?
    [ $_STATUS -eq 0 ] && echo "$Y_c - $MPOINT/$VLABEL mounted ($MOPT)"
    [ $_STATUS -ne 0 ] && echo "$N_c - \"$VLABEL\""
  fi
fi
#====================================================================
```