# In bash, how do I reestablish sftp connection and run it in a script that makes nautilus do it?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sftp

I have a bash script that tests whether the sftp connection exists, very simple one:

```
$ if [ -d ~/.gvfs/sftp for username on 192.168.1.101 ]; then echo "sftp missing" exit; fi
```

Now heres the question:
How do I make the script reestablish the previously connected sftp that still has a cached pass to reconnect without having it depend on if the bash script is on?

Since I have a bookmarked sftp thing in nautilus, i just point and click, presto its reconnected. I need the same for my script which will TERMINATE in a couple of lines; in other words the script only reconnects nautilus and dies, connection stays open...

I am still noobish at sftp, besides connecting...

Extra info: I use Ubuntu for both client and server, and i dont mind entering the ssh pass again if its new conection, any help is appreciated :D

Its critical that sftp wont d/c, or die, when i close script, or it ends, nohup cant be used for script since it will be run >10 times per day

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned entering password each time, check out [passwordless ssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)

Comment: What is a "SFTP connection" here? This is not a standard term, I think.

Comment: @Paulo, sure it is [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol)

Comment: I know what SFTP is, but normally I do not have open connections when I'm not activley transferring files.

Comment: related questions: [How to mount from command line like the Nautilus does?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/483460/600500), [Gnome-mount alternative in Ubuntu 10.04 or how to mount partition with normal user rights](http://superuser.com/q/131918/67711)

Comment: the reason I need to "reconnect" is because I have an opened ssh sftp which I use to stream videos from one comp to another, and when I Hibernate the client comp, the connection needs to be reestablished after turning it back on, so my script needs to remount it, without having to hold it open.                          I am looking into gvfs-mount now :)  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, some research done. You are using the [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) (GNOME Virtual File System), and are looking with a none-GNOME application (bash) on the FUSE mount point of one of the URIs.

I think you can use the `gvfs-mount` command to reconnect, if you know the SFTP URL, but I didn't really find much documentation about this.